# What's the advantage of a trailing underscore in Python naming?

Tags: python, namespaces

I am used to naming Python arguments in this way:

```
my_argument='foo'
```

what's the advantage if I do this instead:

```
my_argument_='foo"
```

as is recommended by PEP008?

There must be a good reason for the trailing underscore, so what is it?

Comment: I don't see anything in PEP-8 that recommends calling an argument `my_argument_` in preference to `my_argument`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Exactly what it gives in the PEP: it allows you to use something that would otherwise be a Python keyword.

```
as_
with_
for_
in_
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I just basically repeated your answer, but you beat me to it!

Comment: what if I don't want to use these keywords？ Would underscore with no trailing be a better choice?

Comment: The keywords will exist whether or not you want to use them. You can't change that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, yes, I know it. I mean, if I don't want to name an arugment in any reserved names. Is it the same to use underscore only without trailing? Or still "my_argument_" is better?

Comment: ..... If you're not trying to use a keyword as a name then why would you bother with a trailing underscore?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That's why I came here to ask this question, because I can't figure it out. Now I'm comfortable enough to name my arguments without this trailing underscore. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for specific (and common) examples. I'm new-ish to `python` so the single `Tkinter` example in PEP 8 (of `class_`) left me unsure I *definitely* understood. This answer removed all doubt.

Answer (score 20):

PEP8 does **not** recommend this naming convention, except for names that would otherwise conflict with keywords. `my_argument` obviously does not conflict, so there is no reason to use an underscore and PEP8 does not recommend that you do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have no sufficient reputation to vote up.

Comment: so can anyone tell why `scikit` uses it so often? Basically for all the outputs after some calculations, e.g. after calling obj.fit() , the output populates otherwise empty *_ params (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Is it good practice?

Comment: The trailing underscore in scikit-learn is a convention to indicate attributes that are only available after an estimator is fitted. Mentioned here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#estimated-attributes

Answer (score 9):

There is no advantage of this convention but it might have special meanings in different projects. For example in scikit-learn, it means that the variable with trailing underscore can have value after `fit()` is called.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.coef_
AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'coef_'
```

In this code above, when you try to get `coef_` attribute of `lr` object, you will get an `AttributeError` because it is not created since `fit` is not called yet.

```
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X, y)
lr.coef_
```

but this time, it will return the coefficients of each column without any errors. This is one of the ways how this convetion is used and it might mean different things in different projects.

Answer (score 2):

Usually naming conventions like this don't have any empiric purpose in python (i.e. they don't do anything special) aside from avoiding conflict between keywords. For example, you wouldn't name a variable `class` would you? You'd name it `class_` to avoid conflict with the built-in keyword.

Comment: don't agree with what you say about `_single_leading_underscore`, PEP8 : `_single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. from M import * does not import objects whose name starts with an underscore.`