# What does it mean for an attribute name to end in an underscore?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Similar question: [What's the advantage of a trailing underscore in Python naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075208/whats-the-advantage-of-a-trailing-underscore-in-python-naming). This addresses advantages/disadvantages, whereas this addresses the reasoning behind doing it, both broadly and specifically to sklearn.

I am looking through the sklearn documentation, and I noticed that the sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV attributes all end in underscore. For example:

- cv_results_
- best_params_
- best_score_

Why is this? What does the underscore do? Please be as broad as possible in your answer (i.e. don't just refer to sklearn's GridSearchCV.

I'm assuming this isn't just an sklearn thing, and I have no idea what the appropriate tag is for this so I'm tagging sklearn. Please correct the tags (or me!).

Comment: The underscore itself has no meaning. It's most likely author's preference for naming convention (of the result(s)). There are many authors that write separate modules in `sklearn`.

Comment: @Jon have you ever come across this convention before? If so, have you observed any informal reason for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the advantage of a trailing underscore in Python naming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075208/whats-the-advantage-of-a-trailing-underscore-in-python-naming)

Comment: In this case, since I know scikit-learn, the underscore behind the attribute name is an indication that this is a variable/value rather than a function. It is just the author's way of making it convenient for you in distinguishing functions and variables by just looking at their names.

Comment: I now added a passage from the sklearn developer guide which addresses it. They have a specific interpretation for this.

Comment: Guys please provide reasoning for downvoting. Such a futile thing to do without providing reasoning.

Comment: And if it's because of possible duplicates, at least check to argument of the questioner, I've seen many cases on SO where people downvote for being a possible duplicate when the questioner has a perfectly good argument.

Comment: @quanty: I would say it depends on your intent. If it was specific for sklearn, then it is no duplicate. If you are interested in general Python, then Vivek Kumar is right, and it is a duplicate. If it is the first, then I think my answer is the more correct one though ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For sklearn, there is a specific interpretation. Check the sklearn [developer guideline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimated-attributes), which has a note on this. The convention is used for attributes of estimators that have a meaningful value after `fit()` was called.

These are then used to for instance check if the estimator was fitted, see for instance [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L236):

```
class LinearModel(six.with_metaclass(ABCMeta, BaseEstimator)):
    """Base class for Linear Models"""

    [...]

    def _decision_function(self, X):
        check_is_fitted(self, "coef_")

   [...]
```