# R: Should I name variables with the same name as function arguments?

Tags: r, object, namespaces

I am seeking guidance on the practice demonstrated in R documentation of creating variables with the same name as function arguments, or of giving a data frame and one of its columns the same name. The latter can lead to code like this:

`delay <- filter(delay(delay >= mean(delay)))`

which strikes me as confusing.

From the examples on the data.frame {base} help page, `fac = fac`:

```
(L3 <- LETTERS[1:3])
# "A" "B" "C"
(fac <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE))
# "C" "C" "B" "A" "B" "A" "B" "A" "C" "C"
(d <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:10, fac = fac))
# x  y fac
# 1  1   C
# 1  2   C
# . . .
```

Re `fac = fac`: Is it considered good practice to name multiple objects/elements with the same name? It seems potentially confusing - I initially thought `fac` was a named argument and went in search of it, to no avail - but perhaps I'm missing the benefit and it's actually more straightforward this way.

Comment: Opinion-based.  In my opinion, it's bad practice assign object names that are the same as function names.  You are just creating confusion for yourself and others.  The argument name thing really doesn't matter as much.

Comment: @Rich Scriven, that was my thought. For me it takes longer to comprehend bc I'm trying to figure out which is the arg, which is the df, which is the var. I'm trying to figure out if there's a good reason to adopt this practice. If not, why do Hadley et al give these as examples?

Comment: @RyanD, fair point.

Comment: I think it depends. The purpose of a variable name is to provide succinct information about what the stored value is. In the case of `factor(..., levels = levels)`, it may be sufficient for a small example, but if you have multiple `levels` vectors you need to name them more specifically. Likewise, `read.csv(file)` is ambiguous, where as `read.csv(h20_temp_data)` is not.

Comment: @RyanD, that's true, I still wouldn't know if the left-hand side was user-defined or built-in.

Comment: In these examples, they are purposely generic, hence, `fac = fac`, because in creating a minimal example it doesn't make sense to create `example_factor_levels <- sample(L3, 10, replace = TRUE)`. The purpose of `fac = fac` is to make it perfectly clear what's being passed to `data.frame`, not because that's how you should name your actual vector.

Comment: @Mako212, good point on generic examples. "Perfectly clear," though, is in the eye of the beholder. My other example (`delay`, `delay`, ...) was derived with slight embellishment from Hadley's R4DS book, and as a learner my eyeballs were bouncing from like-named object to object in perplexity. It wasn't clear to me. But your point that the example may be _intended_ to be perfectly clear (to learners) is taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthesizing my comments into an answer, outside of very simple examples, you should absolutely not name your variables the same thing as a function argument.

Good variable names are essential for writing readable, maintainable code.

## Example 1 (Bad)

```
f1 <- read.csv(file = file, col.names = col.names)
```

## Example 2 (Good)

```
h2o_data <- read.csv(file = h2o_temp_export, col.names = h2otemp_headers)
```

If you didn't write the code in Example 1, there is no indication of what that line of code does without reading through other parts of the program, or testing individual lines of code.

In Example 2, even if you never saw the code, you'd know `h2o_data` contains the .csv data from `h2o_temp_export`, and the `col.names` have been set to values specific to this data set.

Now let's assume you need to add a second data set, following Example 1, assuming you have a different file with different columns, you might write:

```
f2 <- read.csv(file1, col.names = col.names1)
```

Which is totally ambiguous and tells you nothing about `f1` or `f2`. Even worse, you could write over `col.names` setting it to the new values for `f2`, rather than using `col.names1`.

Following Example 2:

```
co2_data <- read.csv(file = co2_concentration_export, 
  col.names = co2_concentration_headers)
```

So unless you are writing a minimal example to highlight a specific use of a piece of code, like those `data.frame` examples, you should always use specific, useful names for additional objects passed to functions.

Edit: also see [Hadley's Style Guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html)

Comment: For an expanded version of that style guide, also by Hadley, see [The tidyverse style guide](http://style.tidyverse.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It can lead to trouble as R will first try to grab from the local environment (inside the function environment) and then from the global environment, which can lead to unexpected side effects. Stylistically, I have seen a lot of R-programmers use a trailing underscore to distinguish between arguments and function variables. i.e.

```
distance = function (velocity_ = 0, time_ = 0){velocity_ * time_}
velocity = 10
time = 5
#Call the function
distance(velocity_ = velocity, time_ = time)
```

Comment: @mrcasswary, interesting way to differentiate arguments and function variables. In python the trailing underscore is a PEP-8 convention used to avoid naming conflicts with Python keywords. The underscore would then be appended to the variable name rather than the keyword. I seem to recall that in python a trailing underscore can also indicate a computed value, but I can't seem to find a confirmation of that right now.

Comment: [See here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075208/whats-the-advantage-of-a-trailing-underscore-in-python-naming)

This happens in r too: Try calling letters -> assigning something to "letters" and then calling letters again.