# Find the max of multiple colums for a particular row and save the header of the max colum into a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
age     col1   col2   col3     max
--------------------------------------
  0     200    150    350             
 16      68    250    50
```

I want to find max value between col1, col2, col3 for every row and update the last column "max" with the column name of the max value

Example in first row, the max value is 350 the "max" column value will be "col3" result like this:

```
age      col1   col2   col3      max
------------------------------------------
  0      200    150    350     col3
 16       68    250    50      col2
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using [`pandas.DataFrame.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
>>> df['max'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df
   age  col1  col2  col3   max
0    0   200   150   350  col3
1   16    68   250    50  col2
```

---

***NB1:*** That being shown, I would go with [`max_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075208/whats-the-advantage-of-a-trailing-underscore-in-python-naming) instead of `max` as new column name since `max` as such refers to an existing method, i.e. [`pandas.DataFrame.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html).

***NB2:*** Also, to prevent `age` from being considered when searching for the maximum, it is probably better to explicite/restrict the search space

```
>>> mxseaspace = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
>>> df['max_'] = df.loc[:, mxseaspace].idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df
   age  col1  col2  col3  max_
0    0   200   150   350  col3
1   16    68   250    50  col2
```

---

<sub>***Toy Data***</sub>

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'age':  [0, 16],
    'col1': [200, 68],
    'col2': [150, 250],
    'col3': [350, 50],
})
```

Comment: Any question @KoKo ?

Comment: No question @keepAlive, that was very clear. I didnt know idxmax was a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method. I think it is faster also.

```
df['Max'] = df.iloc[:,1:].max(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    age col1    col2    col3    Max
0   0   200 150 350 350
1   16  68  250 50  250
```

Comment: Have a closer look at the question and you will see that you are not addressing it. Compare the content of your `Max` column against Koko's (or mine).